Prove that $\sum_{k} \binom{l}{m+k} \binom{s+k}{n} (-1)^k = (-1)^{l+m} \binom{s-m}{n-l}$ using generating functions
This is an identity from Concrete Mathematics (5.24).
Use generating functions to prove that
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{k} \binom{l}{m+k} \binom{s+k}{n} (-1)^k = (-1)^{l+m} \binom{s-m}{n-l}
    \label{eq:identity-to-prove}
\end{equation}
First, get rid of $n$ in the problem itself for the sake of clarity.
Let be $n=t$
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k} \binom{l}{m+k} \binom{s+k}{t} (-1)^k = (-1)^{l+m} \binom{s-m}{t-l}
\end{align*}
It is not clear the non-zero summation bound, rewrite the problem to see it
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=0}^{l-m} \binom{l}{l-m-k} \binom{s+k}{t} (-1)^k     &= (-1)^{l+m} \binom{s-m}{t-l} \\
    \sum_{k=0}^{l-m} \binom{s+k}{t} \binom{l}{l-m-k} (-1)^k     &= (-1)^{l+m} \binom{s-m}{t-l} \\
    \sum_{k=0}^{l-m} \binom{s+k}{t} \binom{l}{l-m-k} (-1)^k     &= (-1)^{l+m} \binom{s-m}{s-m-t+l} \\
    \sum_{k=0}^{l-m} \binom{s+k}{t} \binom{l}{l-m-k} (-1)^k     &= (-1)^{l+m} \binom{s-m}{s-t+l-m} \\
    \sum_{k=0}^{(l-m)} \binom{s+k}{t} \binom{l}{(l-m)-k} (-1)^k &= (-1)^{(l+m)} \binom{s-m}{s-t+(l-m)}
\end{align*}
So I clearly see that it is about to take coefficient of $z^{l-m}$ in product of two generating functions, the $s+k$ choose $t$ is being generated by $z^t/(1-z)^t$ but to find the g.f of the second coefficient appears to be a problem.
Question: Prove the main identity using generating functions (with explanations), it would be nice to fix my own solution

Since it asks you to "use generating functions", can you show how you'd attempt to do so?

For starters we will be evaluating for $\ell \ge m$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\ell-m} {\ell \choose \ell-m-k} {s+k\choose t} (-1)^k.$$
With the given interpretation of the problem definition we see that the
first binomial coefficient enforces the upper range of the sum when
replaced by a coefficient extractor:
$$[z^{\ell-m}] (1+z)^\ell
\sum_{k\ge 0} z^k {s+k\choose t} (-1)^k \quad (1.0)
\\ = [z^{\ell-m}] (1+z)^\ell [w^t] (1+w)^s
\sum_{k\ge 0} z^k (1+w)^k (-1)^k
\\ = [z^{\ell-m}] (1+z)^\ell [w^t] (1+w)^s
\frac{1}{1+z(1+w)} \quad (1.1)
\\ = [z^{\ell-m}] (1+z)^{\ell-1} [w^t] (1+w)^s
\frac{1}{1+wz/(1+z)}
\\ = [z^{\ell-m}] (1+z)^{\ell-1}
\sum_{k=0}^t {s\choose k} (-1)^{t-k} \frac{z^{t-k}}{(1+z)^{t-k}}
\\ = (-1)^t \sum_{k=0}^t {s\choose k} (-1)^k
{\ell-1-t+k\choose \ell-m-t+k}.$$
Here we will assume $t\ge s\ge 0$ to get
$$(-1)^t \sum_{k=0}^t {s\choose k} (-1)^k
{\ell-1-t+k\choose m-1}
\\ = (-1)^t [z^{m-1}] (1+z)^{\ell-1-t}
\sum_{k\ge 0} {s\choose k} (-1)^k (1+z)^k
\\ = (-1)^t [z^{m-1}] (1+z)^{\ell-1-t}
[1-(1+z)]^s
\\ = (-1)^{s+t} [z^{m-1}] (1+z)^{\ell-1-t} z^s
= (-1)^{s+t} {\ell-1-t\choose m-1-s}
\\ = (-1)^{s+t} {\ell-1-t\choose \ell-t-m+s}
= (-1)^{\ell+m} {s-m\choose \ell-t-m+s} \quad (2.0)
\\ = (-1)^{\ell+m} {s-m\choose t-\ell}.$$
This is the claim. This problem is deep in the sense that the ranges
and definitions of the binomial coefficients involved need to be vetted
carefully. For example supposing that $s=t+a$ with $a\ge 1$ where we
treat $a$ as a constant we get
$$(-1)^t \sum_{k=0}^t {t+a\choose k} (-1)^k
{\ell-1-t+k\choose m-1}
\\ = (-1)^{\ell+m} {s-m\choose t-\ell}
- (-1)^t \sum_{k=t+1}^{t+a} {t+a\choose k} (-1)^k
{\ell-1-t+k\choose m-1}
\\ = (-1)^{\ell+m} {s-m\choose t-\ell}
- \sum_{k=1}^a {t+a\choose t+k} (-1)^k
{\ell-1+k\choose m-1}.$$

I added equation numbers for the places are note clear to me.


So in (1.0) you have $z^{k}$ under the sigma sum notation, it should be $-k$ because lower index of binomial coefficient is $l-m-k$?


For equation (2.0) how to shift upper binomial index from $l-1-t$ to $s-m$. What identity is used to simplify sigma summation in (1.1) ?



Seems (1.1) comes from the identity $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1 + x)^n y^n (-1)^n = \frac{1}{1 + (1 + x)y}$. See eq. 15 at https://math.arizona.edu/~faris/combinatoricsweb/generate.pdf

As for 1.0 it is correct, we use $[z^{n-k}] f(z) = [z^n] z^k f(z).$ This is coefficient extraction of formal power series. For 2.0 consult Concrete Mathematics this is called upper negation.

Having upper negation $\binom{r}{k} = (-1)^k \binom{k - r - 1}{k}$, let $r=\ell-1-t$ and $k=\ell-t-m+s$, then it should be $(-1)^{s+t} (-1)^{\ell-t-m+s} = (-1)^{\ell+m+2s}$ in the RHS of (2.0), is that correct?

Yes however the $(-1)^{2s}$ disappears.
